# Issues using strtok in c

Tags: strtok

I would like to have a routine which carries out the following on a string:

1. Use strtok to extract a substring from the string and save to a new char array.
2. Use strtok on the char array to extract more info and store to a char array.
3. Go back to original string and use strtok to continue extracting strings from where I left off.

Is this possible?

Comment: @chadianscot you might want to provide an example, especially on what you mean by points 1 and 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but with issues:

Generic `strtok` is not reentrant, i.e. it stores information about what it's doing in a static location which means you can't jump between strtok'ing your main string, with one delimiter, and your extracted substring, with another delimiter.  You'd need to run `strtok` across your main string completely, and then attack the extracted substrings.

Alternatively, if you have a newer `strtok_r` library routine available, the `_r` indicates this routine is reentrant and you can set up one instance to work on your main string and have another instance work on an extracted substring, and bounce between the two.  `strtok_r` takes an additional argument which is where it saves the state of what it's doing allowing this to work correctly.